# why we have to save the name of CI controller class name by capital letter

Tags: codeigniter-2

when we inheriting the class controller in codeignator so why we have to write the class name by capital letter and why we have to save by class name

> Blockquote

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please clarify your question following the guidelines at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: it is a good idea to develop a consistent convention to indicate what the file contains via its file name. However you can go with another name but in case of a framework, you will need to do the things according to the framework standard. https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html